# sending email to multiple recipients vba

Tags: vba, excel, email

I am trying to send one mail to multiple receipients but I am able to send it to only the last person. Please help me to solve the problem.

Here is the program I have:

```
Sub Mail_Sending_WholWorkbook_Attachment()
'
' Mail_Sending_WholWorkbook_Attachment Macro
' This Macro is used to send the Bidresponse of the day as an attachment to the whole team with cc to santosh
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+B
'
'Working in Excel 2000-2016
'This example send the last saved version of the Activeworkbook
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "nagarjun.balarama@accenture.com"
        .to = "nagarjun.b@bp.com"
        .to = "nagarjungupta@yahoo.com"
        .to = "nagarjunguptab@gmail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "BID RESPONSE"
        .Body = "THIS IS AN AUTOMATIC MAIL SENT THROUGH MACROS." & vbNewLine & "   " & vbNewLine & "Hi Team," & vbNewLine & "   " & vbNewLine & "Attached is the bid response for the day." & vbNewLine & "   " & vbNewLine & "Thanks & Regards," & vbNewLine & "Nagarjun B"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

The code should be :

```
With OutMail
        .to = "nagarjun.balarama@accenture.com;nagarjun.b@bp.com;nagarjungupta@yahoo.com;nagarjunguptab@gmail.com"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "BID RESPONSE"
        .Body = "THIS IS AN AUTOMATIC MAIL SENT THROUGH MACROS." & vbNewLine & "   " & vbNewLine & "Hi Team," & vbNewLine & "   " & vbNewLine & "Attached is the bid response for the day." & vbNewLine & "   " & vbNewLine & "Thanks & Regards," & vbNewLine & "Nagarjun B"
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        'You can add other files also like this
        '.Attachments.Add ("C:\test.txt")
        .Send   'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you just overwrite the "to" value with the latest recipient.
You need to append the recipients by using a semicolon as separator.

Comment: You need to use the `Recipients` property which is a collection. `.Recipients.Add xxxxxx` for each recipient.

Answer (score 1):

Please use ; (semi-colon) like below,

```
.to = "nagarjun.balarama@accenture.com" & ";" & "nagarjun.b@bp.com" & ";" & "nagarjungupta@yahoo.com" & ";" & "nagarjunguptab@gmail.com"
```

or

You can also declare the emails ID's in a separate sheet and refer the cell value.

```
.to = Join(Application.Transpose(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A4").Value), ";")
```

Comment: Why do you need the `" & ";" & "` in the `"nagarjun.balarama@accenture.com" & ";" & "nagarjun.b@bp.com"` ? Surely the `" & ";" & "` is redundant as all of it is text, you might as well write it `"nagarjun.balarama@accenture.com;nagarjun.b@bp.com"`

Comment: we need to use & ";" & in-between email id's.This is the standard format for excel, so id's will club together in "To" address.

Comment: It isn't needed. If you remove the `" & ";" & "` it will work exactly the same. The & is just to join the strings together which you don't need as all of it is a text string. You just need the two " to enclose the entire string.