# Send email to email addresses in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to send email from Excel which sends an attachment using pivot table range saved in Data sheet from A2 and is dynamic every day.

At the `.TO` field I get the error

> Object does not support this method.

```vb
Sub emailtest()

Dim objOutlook As Object
Dim objMail As Object
Dim rngTo As String
Dim rngSubject As String
Dim rngBody As String
Dim LastRow As Long
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

Sheets("Data").Select
LastRow = Worksheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With objMail
.To = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2: A" & LastRow - 1)
.Subject = "Sell Fail Trade"
.Body = "Please find today's sell report"
.Attachments.Add "C\Temp Folder"
.Display 'Instead of .Display, you can use .Send to send the email _
            or .Save to save a copy in the drafts folder
End With
Set objOutlook = Nothing
Set objMail = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: What error do you get? In which line? Have you debuggt your code and checked if all values/objects are as expected?

Comment: `.Body = rngBody = "Please find today's sell report"` doesn't look correct either.

Comment: Thank you Code updated but getting error at "To"

Comment: You can not use a range, which consists of several cells, for `.To` property. Please see e.g.  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40634094/sending-email-to-multiple-recipients-vba/40634465) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985261/how-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-with-addresses-stored-in-excel/42082087) for some solutions

Comment: What value does the `Worksheets("Data").Range("A2: A" & LastRow - 1)` line returns?

Comment: Employee names, which get pasted in to field and they are internal employee so out look autofill the entire email ID.

Comment: You need to build the result string and only then assign a single string built based on the range object to the `To` property.

Answer (score 1):

The `To`-property expects a single string as parameter. If you have more that one person that should receive the mail, you need to concatenate the names with `;`

if `LastRow-1` is larger than 3, you have more than one cell in your range and `Worksheets("Data").Range("A2: A" & LastRow - 1)` will give you a 2-dimensional array of values. And yes, it is 2-dimensional, even if it contains only one column.

There is a nice function in VBA, `join` that can concatenate the content of an array, but in this case it cannot be used as it works only with 1-dimensional arrays.

To you will have to loop over the range manually to create the to-string. I suggest to create a simple, reusable function for that (could be used, for example, also for the cc field).

```
Function join2D(a As Variant, Optional delimiter As String = ";") As String
    ' Check if a is a single value
    If (VarType(a) And vbArray) = 0 Then
        join2D = a
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)
        For j = LBound(a, 2) To UBound(a, 2)
            Dim v
            v = a(i, j)
            If Not IsEmpty(v) And Not IsError(v) Then
                join2D = join2D & IIf(join2D = "", "", delimiter) & CStr(v)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Function
```

You then write in the routine that creates the mail:

```
.To = Join2D(Worksheets("Data").Range("A2: A" & LastRow - 1))
```

Comment: getting type mismatch error on the below line { For i = LBound(a, 1) To UBound(a, 1)}

Comment: Can you check with the debugger what `a` exactly contains? Use the locals window (View->Locals Window).

Answer (score 0):

The `To` property is a string property. It is a semicolon-delimited String list of display names for the To recipients for the Outlook item. So, you need to extract a string from the `Range` object in Excel. For example, you may try using the [Range.Value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.value) property which returns or sets a Variant value that represents the value of the specified range.

```
.To = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2: A" & LastRow - 1).Value
```

or

```
.To = Worksheets("Data").Range("A2: A" & LastRow - 1).Value2
```

If the target range is multidimensional (or consists of multiple cells) you need to build the `To` string based on range values going through each cell and only then assign it to the `To` property.

Comment: That's not the issue. As `Value` is the default property, you can omit it. The problem is that the range contains more that one cell and therefore `Worksheets("Data").Range("A2: A" & LastRow - 1).Value` will return a 2-dimensional array

Comment: I've added that a single cell should be processed and the to string should be built combining each value.